# How to bind Python input command to Key in Bash?

Tags: python, bash

Does someone know how I can bind a command like this to a key combination, let's say Ctrl-m in Bash:

```
python -c "input('need input: ')"
```

I tried

```
bind -x '"\C-m": "python -c '\''input()'\''"'
```

and similar but it does not work. Either I always get errors about the wrong quoting or the input function does not react on keyboard input.
This will be later integrated in a bigger Python Script which I want to call with a key binding.

Thanks!

Comment: If there is a bigger script involved, you will probably be much happier saving it to a file and using `bind -x '"\C-m": "python /path/to/myscript.py"'` than trying to cram it into a single string for the `-c` argument.

Comment: Yes. But this was only a small oneliner to show the problem with Pythons input() function

Comment: It's a well-known problem that nesting quoting context involving the same quotes is a problem. You have at least 4 levels here (the argument to `bind -x`, the macro for `\C-m`, the argument to `python -c`, and the argument to `input` inside the Python script) spread across 3 separate environments (Readline, `bash`, and Python) and only 2 sets of quoting characters (`"` and `'`) to work with, neither of which differentiate between opening and closing characters.

Comment: I should not have noted the quoting problems here, because the real question  is, why the Pythons input() does not work inside a Python script if the script is invoked via bind.